# get data acc to month and count total data in a month

Tags: laravel, postgresql

count total data created monthly

I tried using this query on postgress is shows the exact expected output

```
SELECT
    extract(year from created_at) as year,
    TO_CHAR( TO_TIMESTAMP (extract(month from created_at)::text, 'MM'), 'Month') as month,
    COUNT(id) AS count
FROM project_areas
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY year, month
```

---

```
I tried using this code in laravel bt failed



 return DB::table('project_areas')->select(DB::raw("extract(year from created_at) as year,
    TO_CHAR( TO_TIMESTAMP (extract(month from created_at)::text, 'MM'), 'Month') as month,
    COUNT(id) AS count"))
    ->groupBy('created_at')
    ->orderBy('created_at')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: your selectRaw is very different from the first query

Comment: yes i tried many queries and nothing i tried seemed to work ,and this is just one of them.